# Can sqlite3 handle 30 concurrent update requests gracefully?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

We like the simplicity of sqlite3 but are concerned about its ability to handle concurrent updates gracefully. Our web app is for about 30 users (50 users maximum) who has rights to update and a number of web users (let's say 500 web users) who can only read the page. Those 30 (50) users likely will not do update simultaneously. Daily update to the db should be no more than 1000 updates (consider saving one db record into a table as ONE update) on regular base. The update activity most likely happens during the 9am-5pm work hour.

Since sqlite3 locks the whole db for update (not sure if it locks for read request), our question is that is sqlite3 powerful enough to handle the concurrent updates gracefully in our situation without showing the exception error.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Sqlite shouldn't in itself be producing an exception because it is receiving too many requests - but I expect it will effectively make subsequent requests wait, thus causing simultaneous visitors to contend for database locks. If you've been getting an exception, it may be that your web system has timed out before the database has answered - which would be surprising if you are getting only ~1k updates per working day. I'm pretty sure Sqlite can handle that `:)`.

Comment: We don't have real data to verify our app with sqlite3 and that's why we want to find if others may have the answer for us. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you already have enough information about how SQLite works. So the answer to your question is "yes" it can handle. But the real question is what would be the performance? It depends on the frequency of updates/inserts to your database. Updates will lock and keep reads waiting.

Let's say the performance is acceptable and you use it. What if your database gets corrupted? Even most advanced DBMS systems can have corrupted data. There can be many reasons of this from server shutdown to bugs. If your SQLite gets corrupted, as far as I know it is harder to recover the database file.

I'd strongly suggest don't risk and use a non-embedded DBMS.

Comment: Did you mean we should not use sqlite3 even it can handle the load? How hard is it to recover sqlite3 database with backup? Is it different from recovering mysql db?

Comment: @ata-s: Sqlite _is_ an RDBMS (Wikipedia: "sqlite is an ACID-compliant embedded relational database management system contained in a small (~275 kB) C programming library").

Comment: Also, [from the sqlite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q21): "SQLite does not corrupt database files, except in the case of very rare bugs (see DatabaseCorruption) and even then the bugs are normally difficult to reproduce. Even if your application crashes in the middle of an update, your database is safe. The database is safe even if your OS crashes or takes a power loss. The crash-resistance of SQLite has been extensively studied and tested and is attested by years of real-world experience by millions of users."

Comment: Sounds like sqlite3 is good enough for our projected load. Is anyone having experience with many sqlite3 db engines (for example, 100) loaded into one web server? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @halfer it is embedded DBMS. There's a slight difference. Even so I put the "non-embedded" keyword to there for just to make it more clear. Also SQLite depends on your software and it depends on the OS, so it can get corrupted. Normal OS files can get corrupted, how can SQLite not? Please read the page for more http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Comment: @user938363 no SQLite 3 is not good enough for you. Let me give you an example when it is good enough, one of our projects we are 3 people and we use Trac project management software a few times in a week, and SQLite is perfectly fine. You are talking about 50 writers and 500 readers, I'm repeating it again, just don't risk it! Use speed for MySQL, use features for PostgreSQL (it even has table inheritance!). They are both free, why would you risk it? You also will get a better caching mechanism. In SQLite you probably need to use an external cache mechanism to have good caching.

Comment: Also I'm not saying SQLite is bad, it is a beautiful software, I love it, we can ship it with our client-side software, we can easily back it up, it saves us from using text files, but in your case a non-embedded DBMS is better.

Comment: I am looking forward to use SQLite3 in a distributable desktop app for our integrated solution. For simplicity, we don't want our user to know the detail of the database. They just have to know how to install in a very easy manner